# Передача данных между контроллерами

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Подскажите, у меня есть 3 контроллера, в первом человек выбирает день недели, дальше выбирает пару и заполняет данные о ней(приложение с расписанием для преподавателей), сейчас если записать данные в понедельник, они же отобразятся и в других днях недели, как это исправить?

Мой код для выбора дня недели

```
enum DaysOfWeek: Int {
    case UpMonday = 11
    case UpTuesday = 12
    case UpWednesday = 13
    case UpThursday = 14
    case UpFriday = 15
    case downMonday = 16
    case downTuesday = 17
    case downWednesday = 18
    case downThursday = 19
    case downFriday = 20
}

@IBAction func weeksButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let day = DaysOfWeek.init(rawValue: sender.tag) else { return }
    switch day {
    case .UpMonday:
        let mondayTable = self
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: mondayTable)
        break
    case .UpTuesday:
        let tuesdayTable = self
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: tuesdayTable)
        break
    case .UpWednesday:
        let wednesdayTable = self
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: wednesdayTable)
        break
    case .UpThursday:
        let thursdayTable = self
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: thursdayTable)
        break
    case .UpFriday:
        let fridayTable = self
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: fridayTable)
        break
    case .downMonday:
        let downMonday = self
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: downMonday)
        break
    case .downTuesday:
        let downTuesday = self
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: downTuesday)
        break
    case .downWednesday:
        let downWednesday = self
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: downWednesday)
        break
    case .downThursday:
        let downThursday = self
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: downThursday)
        break
    case .downFriday:
        let downFriday = self
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: downFriday)
        break
    }
}
```

[image: фото]

Код сохранения введенных данных в КорДату

```
class SheduleTeacher: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var subjectLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var roomLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var groupLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var captainLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var subjectField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var roomField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var timeField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var groupField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var captainField: UITextField!

let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "UserOne")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            subjectField.text = data.value(forKey: "subject21") as? String
            roomField.text = data.value(forKey: "room21") as? String
            timeField.text = data.value(forKey: "time21") as? String
            emailField.text = data.value(forKey: "emailGroup21") as? String
            groupField.text = data.value(forKey: "group21") as? String
            captainField.text = data.value(forKey: "captain21") as? String
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed")
    }

    subjectLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    roomLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    timeLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    emailLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    groupLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    captainLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
}

@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "UserOne", in: context)
let newUser = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
newUser.setValue(self.subjectField!.text, forKey: "subject21")
newUser.setValue(self.roomField!.text, forKey: "room21")
newUser.setValue(self.timeField!.text, forKey: "time21")
newUser.setValue(self.emailField!.text, forKey: "emailGroup21")
newUser.setValue(self.groupField!.text, forKey: "group21")
newUser.setValue(self.captainField!.text, forKey: "captain21")
do {
try context.save()
} catch {
print("Failed saving")
}
}
}
```

Comment: А куда вы данные о внесённых парах записываете? Если в UserDefaults, то смотрите мой ответ на ваш вопрос от 1 мая. Иначе дополните вопрос, потому что спрашиваете вы про хранение данных, а прикладываете скриншоты с UI (как эти скриншоты вообще могут помочь в ответе?)

Comment: Добавил код как я сохраняю, использовал ваш совет, сохраню в CoreData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На основе предоставленной Вами информации смею предположить, что все необходимые данные можно поместить в такую структуру:

```
struct Lesson {

    //Из первого UIViewController
    var dayOfWeek: DaysOfWeek = .UpMonday
    //Из второго UIViewController
    var lessonIndex: Int = 0
    //Из третьего UIViewController
    var subject: String = ""
    var room: String = ""
    var email: String = ""
    var group: String = ""
    var captain: String = ""
}
```

Эта структура должна быть у каждого из Ваших `UIViewController`, добиться этого можно, к примеру, за счёт общего базового класса:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var lesson = Lesson()
}
```

Перед демонстрацией экрана с выбором пары необходимо корректно инициализировать соответствующий `UIViewController`. Для этого придётся переписать немножко `weeksButtonPressed`:

```
@IBAction func weeksButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let day = DaysOfWeek.init(rawValue: sender.tag) else { return }
    switch day {
    case .UpMonday:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: sender) // sender - это кнопка, её tag хранит информацию о выбранном дне недели
        break
    /* Обработка других дней */
    }
}
```

Если учесть, что Вы используете переходы для отображения `UIViewController`, то теперь у Вас должен появиться подобный фрагмент кода:

```
class ChoosePairController: BaseViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "showTeacherLessons", let destinationController = segue.destination as? BaseViewController {

            if let senderTag = (sender as? UIView)?.tag,
               let dayOfWeekValue = DaysOfWeek(rawValue: senderTag) {

                self.lesson.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeekValue
            }
            destinationController.lesson = self.lesson
        }
    }
}
```

Данные для Core Data Вам нужно брать из `lesson`:

```
newUser.setValue(lesson.dayOfWeek.rawValue, forKey: "dayOfWeek21")
```

Comment: Подскажите а как этот код будет определять какой день недели нажал пользователь?

Comment: @ИванПоддубнов Ознакомьтесь с обновлённой версией ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите, вопрос о передаче данных между модулями внутри приложения (а вью-контроллеры можно считать отдельными модулями) - очень важный, возможно, даже более важный, чем вопрос об организации кода внутри самого модуля.

Так вот сейчас вы хотите определить, как будут передаваться данные, которые пользователь постепенно заполняет на нескольких экранах.

Можно предложить класс или структуру некоего контекста (что это, расписание?.. пусть будет тогда LessonScheduleContext), поля в котором будут заполняться при прохождении user flow, который вы привели на скриншоте. При создании следующего вью-контроллера в стеке, текущий контроллер будет передавать контекст в него - через метод prepareForSegue, если вы используете segue. Когда в конечном счете на последнем экране пользователь нажмет "ОК" ("Сохранить", etc.) вы данные из этого объекта LessonScheduleContext сохраните в вашу локальную базу данных, например, в CoreData. При этом для хранения вы, конечно, будете использовать уже другой класс, LessonScheduleContext - это тип, который предназначен исключительно для хранения информации в рамках user flow по добавлению урока. Избегайте излишней связности внутри проекта.

А положить данные в UserDefaults, чтобы извлечь их на следующем экране - точно не лучшее использование UserDefaults.